# Jump to start of a file while using enumerate() in a loop

Tags: python, counter, enumerate

I'm using enumerate in a loop to get number of line in witch for example is declaration of a function in a .c file. I store names of those functions in a simple table and search for its name in file. My script works, but when there is a situation where index of function in a table is different than in file, my scripts skips that function. So i.e.

```
list_func_name = ['func_1', 'func_2', 'func_3', 'func_4']
```

And my .c file looks like (number of line and name of function):

```
53289 func_1
53290 func_2
53291 func_4
53292 func_3
```

My script:

```
def enumerate_item():
with open(current_directory + r"\D_Out_Clean\\" + list_file_name[id], "r+") as f_iat:
    p = 0
    no_of_line = 1
    for num, line in enumerate(f_iat, no_of_line):
        if r'void '+list_func_name[p] in line:
            print("Found item at line: ", num)
            p+=1
            num = 1
```

I have a problem with finding func_3 when it's after func_4. My script don't start over from line number 1 and I don't know how to fix this. I tried to reset the counter, but value stored in line variable isn't reset, so it just goes from where it found last function name and thus it's not tracing back, skipping every name that could be before of func_1.

So the current result is:

```
Found item func_1 at line:  53289
Found item func_2 at line:  53290
Found item func_3 at line:  53292
```

And then it just goes looking for func_4 in line #53293, 53294 ... . How should I fix this, so it will reset to a line #1 of my .c file?

Comment: Unless you save all lines, your algorithm cannot know if a certain string was already in the file. So unless you want to change your design completely, just start at the beginning of the file each time. It's not efficient, but depending on runtime, it might not matter at all and be faster than designing a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest (but not the most efficient) way would be something like:

```
list_func_name = ["func_1", "func_2", "func_3", "func_4"]

def enumerate_item():
    with open(current_directory + r"\D_Out_Clean\\" + list_file_name[id], "r+") as f_iat:
        for num, line in enumerate(f_iat, start=1):
            for func in list_func_name:
                if "void " + func in line:
                    print(f"Found {func} at line: ", num)
```